# How can i trim just specific characters from my string?

Tags: javascript

I have the following array

```
const re = '    ';
var arr  = ['\t', '\n3\t3', '\n\t', '\n3\t3', '\n2\t', '\n\t2', '\n']
```

i need to trim the \t and \n characters from strings.
So when i try

```
for(let i = 0;i < arr.length;i++) {
let row = arr[i].split(re);
console.log(row);
}
```

i get

```
['', '']
['\n3', '3']
['\n', '']
['\n3', '3']
['\n2', '']
['\n', '2']
['\n']
```

i can't find a way to remove the \n charactes here when i get to this point so
when i have just `\n` as element then it should be replaced with '' - empty string.

If the character includes other things inside for example

```
\n2
```

so \n before or after a number then i shold get just the number and to have just 2 inside

How can i replace this \n cahracters

Comment: how should your output look like ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple replace function:

```js
var arr  = ['\t', '\n3\t3', '\n\t', '\n3\t3', '\n2\t', '\n\t2', '\n']
var row="";
var newArr=[];

for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    row = parseInt(arr[i].replace('\tn',""));
    if(isNaN(row) === false){newArr.push(row)}
}

console.log(newArr);
```

First `replace("\,t,n")` your characters, then `parseInt()` to convert remaining string-numbers to integers, lastly distinguish those numbers and `push()` them to a new array.

Answer (score 1):

Use `replace()` function of string combined with `map()` function of array. It will look like this

```js
arr.map(c => c.replace(/(\n|\t)/gi, ''))
```

Output will be:

`[ '',   '33', '', '33', '2',  '2', '' ]`

If you don't want to see empty strings in array you can just filter them with .filter(Boolean)

```js
arr.map(c => c.replace(/(\n|\t)/gi, '')).filter(Boolean)
```

Output will be:

`[ '33', '33', '2', '2' ]`

Answer (score 0):

Reference: [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

It is not good practice to do with split method. You can use replace method instead.

Here is example what you want to do:

```js
var someText = "Here's some text.\n It has some line breaks that will be removed \r using Javascript.\r\n";

someText = someText.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");

console.log(someText);
```

*You can edit your replace method what you want to use in it.*

**Note: "/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm" this is a regex.**

Answer (score 0):

You may do a regex replacement on `[\t\n]+` to remove these characters:

```js
var arr = ['\t', '\n3\t3', '\n\t', '\n3\t3', '\n2\t', '\n\t2', '\n'];
var output = arr.map(x => x.replace(/[\t\n]+/g, ""));
console.log(output);
```

Note that if there could be *other* whitespace characters which you also want to remove, just do a regex replacement on `\s+`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [String.prototype.trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim). It cleans `\n` and `\t` as well. It is only for trimming. It will not remove characters in the middle of the string.
Example:

```
const arr = ['\t', '\n3\t3', '\n\t', '\n3\t3', '\n2\t', '\n\t2', '\n'];
const newArr = arr.map(val => val.trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const re = ' ';                                                       
var arr  = ['\t','\n3\t3','\n\t','\n3\t3','\n2\t','\n\t2','\n']   
 
for(let i=0 ; i< arr.length ; i++) 
{                                                                         
    let row = arr[i].replaceAll('\t','').replaceAll('\n','').split(re);
    console.log(row);
}
```